# PHP Check if URL is a subdomain URL or not

Tags: php, string, function, url, dns

I wrote a function to validate if the given URL is a sub-domain URL or not.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 

function isSubDomain($myDomain)
{

    $myDomain=parse_url($myDomain)["host"];

    if(strstr($myDomain,'.',true)=='www')
    {
        return 0;
        break;
    }

    $domainExtentions=array(
                            '.com',
                            '.net',
                            '.org',
                            '.co.uk'
                            );

    foreach($domainExtentions as $extention)
    {
        if($extention==substr($myDomain,-(strlen($extention))))
        {
            $mydomain=substr($myDomain,0,-(strlen($extention)));
        }

    }

    if (substr_count($mydomain,'.')>0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

}

//Sub-domain exists
    if(isSubDomain('http://SUBDOMAIN.hezi-gangina.com/pua/pug/index.php?q=balataLeStus'))
    {
        echo'This url contains sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo'This url doesn\'t have any sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }

//No subdomain (www)    
    if(isSubDomain('http://www.hezi-gangina.com/pua/pug/index.php?q=haMetrixHeshbon'))
    {
        echo'This url contains sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo'This url doesn\'t have any sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }

//Non www url (and no sub-domain)
    if(isSubDomain('http://hezi-gangina.com/pua/pug/index.php?q=einLehaSikuy'))
    {
        echo'This url contains sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo'This url doesn\'t have any sub-domain!';
        echo "\r\n";
    }
```

Looks like working perfectly (and off-course the domain extensions should be fully updated) and that brings the question...

1. Is there any "right outside the box" PHP command that store an array with all domain extensions or do I need to update it manually?
2. AFTER removing all possible extensions from any given URL **AND** the domain is not starting with www... Is it possible that it won't be a sub-domain?

Comment: It sounds like your question is not about the code you posted.  Can you please give examples to support your questions?  For example, show an example URL for question 2.

Comment: @dj99 In other words I'm asking if it's possible that the domain would be : http://my.domain.co.uk/ and "my" won't be a sub-domain (a part of the domain) ?

Comment: Yes! I've just checked... It is possible to register a domain with a . as a part of a domain which makes it IMPOSSIBLE to detect if it's a real sub-domain or it's a part of the domain name.

Comment: Also in Zealand the URLs are `mysite.co.nz` just for Example

Answer (score 0):

What if you exploded it at the "."?  You could look to see if the next to last part is .co to determine if the extension is one or two parts long.  You could look at the first part to see if it is www and then a count of the parts could tell you if it is a subdomain.